# Create multiple ListViews with scrollbar in C#, inside another responsive container in UWP

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I have a container in Xaml (currently StackPanel, which I know is not the best, but only thing working O.K for me). Inside that container I need to create undefined number of lists (max 10) in the cs file.
The problem is, when lists are long they don't have scrollbar, unless I limit the StackPanel's Height, but that restrics app's responsiveness.
Using Grid also problematic since I need the container to handle the placement of each new created ListView.
I also saw related solutions, but they always refer to viewlists in Xaml and not C#.

My Xaml code:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Name ="sensorDataStackPanel" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ComboBox x:Name="sensorComboBox" PlaceholderText="Pick sensor" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=sensors_collection}" 
                      SelectionChanged="SensorComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
        <StackPanel Name="AxiseslistViewStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" MaxHeight="300"/>

    </StackPanel>  
</Grid>
```

C# code --> when user pick sensor in ComboBox the lists are created accordingly inside the StackPanel:

```
public sealed partial class Layout_Tab : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Sensor> sensors_collection;
    public ObservableCollection<Axis> axises;

    .......
    private void SensorComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        Sensor chosen_sensor = (Sensor)comboBox.SelectedItem;
        axises = chosen_sensor.axisesList;
        this.AxiseslistViewStackPanel.Children.Clear();

        foreach(var axis in axises)
        {
            ListView listView = new ListView { Header = axis.AxisName, SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple,
            ShowsScrollingPlaceholders =true, CanBeScrollAnchor = true};
            foreach(var antenna in axis.inUseAntennaList)
            {
                listView.Items.Add(antenna);
            }
            this.AxiseslistViewStackPanel.Children.Add(listView);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a pic with defined StackPanel height:

[image: 2 lists example with viewlist]

Thanks for all

EDIT:
After changing to GridView still get the same results:

```
<GridView Name="AxiseslistViewStackPanel" ItemsSource="{x:Bind axises}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="tests:Axis">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind AxisName}"/>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind inUseAntennaList}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

This is how GridView with no height limit:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a `GridView` as a container instead of `StackPanel`?

Comment: When using GridView how can I add ListViews one after another? They all be one on top of the other. I can't define rows and columns since I don't know how many ListViews i'll have.

Comment: No, bro. `GridView` won't place one child on top of another. Please have a look at the doc here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/listview-and-gridview and here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GridView
I strongly believe `GridView` will be the perfect control for your scenario.

Comment: `GridView` places children on rows and columns, the best part is that you won't have to mention how many rows or how many columns, it will automatically decide based on the available space it has.

Comment: Also, use the [XAML Controls Gallery](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MSVH128X2ZT) to see yourself which control does what.

Comment: Hi thanks for the idea, I tried GridView but same thing, If not limited by Height then list is going out of range. I can't use the property ScrollViewer.CanContentRenderOutsideBounds="False", since my minimum target version does not support this.

Comment: Can you show a snapshot?

Comment: I added the code to EDIT section, with example pic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to solve it I used eventually Grid as container instead of StackPanel, thats the only change.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Name ="sensorDataStackPanel" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="30"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="sensorComboBox" PlaceholderText="Pick sensor" ItemsSource="{x:Bind sensorsCollection, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                          SelectionChanged="SensorComboBox_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Name="AxiseslistViewStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

CS:

```
private async Task RefreshSensorView()
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        AxiseslistViewStackPanel.Children.Clear();

        foreach (var axis in axisesCollection)
        {
            var axisListView = new ListView
            {
                Header = "Axis: " + axis.AxisNumber,
                SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple,
                ShowsScrollingPlaceholders = true,
            };

            axisListView.ItemsSource = axis.inUseAntennaList;

            AxiseslistViewStackPanel.Children.Add(axisListView);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason `ListView` can scroll is because they have a `ScrollViewer` internal.
When you place a `ListView` inside a parent `StackPanel`, if the `ListView` height is greater than the viewport, the parent panel becomes the full height of the `ListView`. You could verify this with getting StackPanel and `ActualHeight` in listview item click method. That is reason why the listview works when fixed the `ListView` height.

The fix is simple: put the parent layout panel in a `ScrollViewer`.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Name="RootLayout" >
        <Button
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Click="Button_Click"
        Content="AddListView"
        />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Same thing.. Might be the problem I put this whole thing inside another StackPanel?

Comment: Hi,unfortunately no.  StackPanel worked for me only if I limited it to specific height. Only solution for me is to avoid completely from StackPanel And use only Grid.

Comment: If you solved , you could also post your solution below.